# How to bulk insert data using csv with nulls values inside the csv file?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL Server and I would like to bulk import data into a table using a `.csv` file.

May I know what is the SQL command to do it?

Comment: Do you have Sql Server Management Studio With you? Hope this data import is one time thing

Answer (score 0):

Select your database click right on it  -> Go to tasks and you will find Import option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Server's BCP utility to Import and Export bulk data. Check out the following link to get started:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-and-export-bulk-data-by-using-the-bcp-utility-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

Run following script to load all the data from CSV to database table.

```
BULK
INSERT CSVTest
FROM 'c:\csvtest.txt'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```